# How to delete a GA property connected to Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

In the Google Analytics Admin console, I have create a new property in order to track an Android mobile application.

When asked, I have connected the property to a Firebase project (I have selected the one I want from the list) and then I clicked on "Connect App".

Now I would like to delete this property from Google Analytics. So I select the property, I click on "Move to Trash Can" and finally I confirm that I want to delete this property clicking on "Delete Property".

But instead of deleting the property, a "Page Not Found" toast is displaying...

How can I delete this property ? Is there another way ?

Thank you in advance for you help !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related. May be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There is a feed back button at the bottom of the page to report the error.

Comment: @DaImTo : Thk you. I send the issue. I hope they will be able to help me :)

Comment: In the mean time i am going to send the team an email looks like a bug to me